# Single View Template add navigation

Tags: ios, storyboard

So I started out an app by selecting the single view application template. I have added some more views using storyboard and everything was working good but I now wanted a button to take the user back to the first view using `[ self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];` but the issue being the template started out as just a viewController. Is there a way to turn the first view into a navigation or root view to make this work or do I have to start all over in a page application template??

Comment: Select your viewController, from top menu Editor / Embed In / Select navigation controller should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Insert a navigation controller in your storyboard before your root view controller.
2. Set the navigation controller as your initial view controller.
3. Set the navigation controller's root view controller to what was originally your first view controller.